# Cursor null exception in Samsung galaxy s3

Tags: android

```
try{

     String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imgPath,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        path = cursor.getString(columnIndex); }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cursor Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Log Cat:

```
04-26 14:07:12.920: W/System.err(18580): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 14:07:12.930: W/System.err(18580):    at com.example.camera.CameraAct$10$1.run(CameraAct.java:365)
04-26 14:07:12.930: W/System.err(18580):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-26 14:07:12.930: W/System.err(18580):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-26 14:07:12.930: W/System.err(18580):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-26 14:07:12.930: W/System.err(18580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
04-26 14:07:12.930: W/System.err(18580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 14:07:12.930: W/System.err(18580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
```

Note: i dont know what is the reason for null pointerexception from cursor. i used this code for samsung galaxy s3.

Comment: Post your stack trace from logcat

Comment: ¿Have you defined imgPath?

I recommend you to check if cursor != null before using it. Also, it could that filePathColumn doesn't exists for every device (Could be protected, or could be pointing to an non-present removable memory )

Paste a larger piece of code to help you, please.

Comment: your toast is incorrect. it logs when cursor is empty, not null.

Comment: @Aleks G i edit my logcat.

Comment: @Ger Soto yes, i already defined imgPath.

Comment: Your `NullPointerException` doesn't seem to be related to the cursor, but is happening in the `run` method in an anonymous class in CameraACt.java, what's the code around line 365 there?

Comment: @AleksG at if(cursor.getCount()>0) because cursor is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imgPath,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    path = cursor.getString(columnIndex); }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cursor Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

it obviously that `getContentResolver().query` return a null cursor. You need make sure the `query(imgPath,filePathColumn, null, null, null)` is correct, specially the `imgPath`